# Why does the following approximation hold?

Tags: mathematical-economics, search-and-matching

In Essential Mathematics for Economic Analysis, on page 426 there is a model on gains from search where profit function is given as:

$$\pi (t) = [p^0 -p(t)]x^0 -wt$$

$t$ is time, $p$ price, $x$ quantity and $w$ wage. Later in the book on the same page it is stated that the gain expected from finding a lower price is:

$$\pi (t) = [p(t^*)-p(t^*+1)]x^0 $$

which is approximately equal to $-p(t)x^0$. I think I can understand everything else in this model but I don't understand how $[\pi (t) = p(t^*)-p(t^*+1)]x^0 \approx -p(t^*)x^0$. The book does not explain this.